# How to send one email to multiple contacts with separate individual follow-up activities

Tags: email, activity

If I send an email to forty contacts, I can opt to generate a follow-up activity (eg phone call). That's great, except that it creates one single follow-up activity for all the contacts. I would like to generate separate follow-up activities, one for each contact, so that I can record the different sequences of activities which follow on the from the initial mailing. Is there any way of doing this?

Alternatively would it be difficult to duplicate the one follow-up activity (with forty contacts) into forty activities, each with one contact?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jern - I may be misunderstanding your work flow, but if you choose to set create an Activity from the search results then you can specify that there should be a single Activity per contact, not one for all the contacts selected. Are you saying that if you do the above, but also specify 'follow up' there is no option to again specify the follow up should be 'one per contact'

Comment: Hi petednz - that's a useful tip, which could be a workaround for us. Thank you. I was looking for the same "Create a separate activity for each contact" option in the Schedule Follow-up Activity section of the send-email dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

(converting comment to answer)

If you choose to create an Activity from the search results then you can specify that there should be a single Activity per contact, not one for all the contacts selected. At that point, if you specify there should be a 'follow up' then the follow up should also be 'one per contact'